# javascript events, onfocus

Tags: javascript, events

Now I'm changing default behavior of onfocus(onclick etc) events like this:

```
<div onfocus="my(this);"> </div>
function my(e){
    e.style.backgroundColor = "red";//here we do not use getElementById
}
```

This works good until I need to attach events from javascript. Of course we can use `addEventListener("focus", my)` but in this case we do not send `this` value and I need to find to by `getElementById`, but this is not good for me. How can I solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: `this` is automatically set by the javascript engine. You should pass the `event` parameter, ex: `onfocus="my(event);"` or simply access `this` inside `functin my()`

Comment: How will you determine the ID of the getelementbyid?

Comment: RaraituL , so how should I implement this?

Comment: just how winhowes answered

Comment: Raraitul, no his anweser is not right.
Here is my solution with your hint
<div contenteditable = "true" id = "qw">
      dsfdafsdafjsda.
     </div>
<script>
function my(){
 this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
document.getElementById("qw").addEventListener("focus", my);
</script>

Comment: The solution I provided will work for onfocus if you add the `contenteditable="true"` attribute. But @Mouser also has provided a correct solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Change your html to this:

```
<div onclick="my(event);"> test</div>
```

And your JS to this:

```
function my(e){
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = "red";//here we do not use getElementById
}
```

`e.target`is the element which received the event.

Comment: @Mouser I tried to keep it as close to the original code as possible

Answer (score 0):

```js
    document.querySelector("div").addEventListener("click", my, false); //select the only div

    function my(e){
        e.target.style.backgroundColor = "red";//here we do not use getElementById
    }
```

```html
<div> Test div </div>
```

`Target` is the keyword. I would still use `addEventListener` since it's a more standard approach than inline events. Also (you don't need it now) it natively send the `this` keyword and it allows other similar events to be attached without overriding them.

Answer (score 0):

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Drifter/6rgamjxz/)

Add a class to each div you want to use for focus **with a tabindex**. Tabindexes can make divs focus

```
<div class="sofocus" tabindex="0">
```

And now you can just add the eventlistener

```
var focusDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.sofocus');
for(var i = 0; i < focusDivs.length; i++){
  var div = focusDivs[i];
}
```

Bind each div with the event

```
div.addEventListener("focus", styleItRed);
```

And also for not focussing anymore

```
div.addEventListener("blur", removeColor);
```

With that in mind you can create the functions

```
function styleItRed(){
    this.style.color = 'red';
}

function removeColor(){
    this.style.color = 'inherit';
}
```